# ActiveRecord Update_all to variable value

Tags: ruby, activerecord, update-all

I'm looking for a way to update all record with certain condition their cur_val + 100:

I have a table Suggestions with **id** and **score** fields, and I want all the entries with specific ids to receive a score bump, e.g:

```
Suggestion.where(id: ids_list).update_all(score: score+100)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: why this answer isn't accepted ? It's correct as far as I can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try plain `SQL`, read about [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all):

```
Suggestion.where(id: ids_list).update_all('score = score + 100')
```

But remember `update_all` not trigger `Active Record` callbacks or validations.

#### Some tips:

You can do it in `Ruby` but this very bad:

```
Suggestion.where(id: ids_list).find_each do |x|
  x.update(score: x.score + 100)
end
```

Things like this should happen in database.